# I don't understand the code for training a classifier in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I don't understand the line `labels.size(0)`. I'm new to Pytorch and been quite confused about the data structure.

```
correct = 0
total = 0
with torch.no_grad():
   for data in testloader:
      images, labels = data
      outputs = net(images)
      _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
      total += labels.size(0)
      correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

print('Accuracy of the network on the 10000 test images: %d %%' % (
    100 * correct / total))`
```

Comment: Which parts of that code cause that confusion?

Answer (score 1):

`labels` is a Tensor with dimensions `[N, 1]`, where `N` is equal to the number of samples in the batch. [`.size(...)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.size) returns a subclass of tuple (`torch.Size`) with the dimensions of the Tensor, and `.size(0)` returns an integer with the value of the first (0-based) dimension (i.e., `N`).

Answer (score 1):

***To answer your question***

In PyTorch, `tensor.size()` allows you to check out the shape of a tensor.

In your code,

```
images, labels = data
```

`images` and `labels` will each contain `N` number of training examples depends on your batch size. If you check out the shape of labels, it should be `[N, 1]`, where N is the size of mini-batch training example.

***A bit of prescience for those who are new to training a neural network.***

When training a neural network, practitioners will forward pass the dataset through the network and optimize the gradients.

Say your training dataset contain 1 million images, and your training script is designed in a way to pass all 1 million images in a single epoch. The problem with this approach is it will take a really long time for you to receive feedback from your neural network. This is where mini-batch training comes in.

In PyTorch, the DataLoader class allows us to split the dataset into multiple batches. If your training loader contains 1 Million examples and batch size is 1000, you will expect each epoch will iterate 1000 step through all the mini-batches. This way, you can observe and optimize the training performance better.

Comment: There are other benefits for using mini batches other than what @Rex Low has described, as well as some downsides, I suggest reading this :
https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-mini-batch-gradient-descent-configure-batch-size/ to learn more.